# MySQL - one to many select from two tables

Tags: java, mysql

I have two tables one containing names of people (+ other data) and the other containing tags associated with people.

people:

```
person_id  name     other ...
1          Name 1   ...
2          Name 2   ...
3          Name 3   ...
...
```

tags:

```
person_id  tag_id
1          2
1          3
2          6
1          7
2          8
1          1
...
```

I would like to select the info from both tables at the same time such that the result would be something like:

person_id=1, name=Name 1, tag_id=[2,3,7,1]

So that I can do something like the following using Spring JDBC RowMapper:

```
@Override
public PersonDetails mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
    PersonDetails personDetails = new GameDetails();
    personDetails.setId(rs.getLong("person_id"));
    personDetails.setName(rs.getString("name"));
    personDetails.setTags((int[]) rs.getArray("tag_id").getArray());
    return personDetails;
}
```

Comment: It's really unlikely that `person_id` would be stored in a `tags` table. Instead, that might be the `person_tags` table. Just sayin'

Comment: @Strawberry ok sorry I just realised what you mean, you mean the table name is not clear and should be renamed. Not that the data is wrong. In actual fact I have four tables person_basic, person_adv, tags and person_tags. It is actually person_tags that I am referencing as tags above so I am actually already doing as you say, I just typed it out quickly and skipped a few characters ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
SELECT
  t.person_id,
  p.name,
  GROUP_CONCAT(t.tag_id SEPARATOR ',') `tag_id`
FROM
  tags t
  JOIN people p ON t.person_id = p.person_id
GROUP BY
  t.person_id
```

This will result in

```
person_id   name    tag_id
1           Name1   3,7,1,2
2           Name2   6,8
```

See also [group_concat](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: I had spent a bit of time looking into the group_concat function for this but i wasn't sure how to use it. I'll be able to check this later and report back.

Comment: This works. However, for my situation I had to create a stored procedure as I was working with Spring JDBC which seemingly does not allow you to use GROUP_CONCAT, I think because it is performing two statements or something, I don't fully understand. I'll try to update my question with an example of the result that I made using this SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are just returning `PersonDetails` I am assuming your query is suppose to return only one `PersonDetails` and not a list of it. For this you can you can alternatively do following

> SELECT * FROM people p INNER JOIN tags t ON p.person_id = t.person_id where p.person_id = "your_person_id"

```
@Override
public PersonDetails mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
    PersonDetails personDetails = new GameDetails();
    personDetails.setId(rs.getLong("person_id"));
    personDetails.setName(rs.getString("name"));
    List<Integer> tagList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    while(rs.next())
    {
        tagList.add()rs.getInt(tag_id);
        personDetails.setTags((int[]) rs.getArray("tag_id").getArray());
    }
    personDetails.setTags(tagList.toArray());
    return personDetails;
}
```

Even if you want to return List if PersonDetails create a HashMap and keep storing objects in it. For each iteration check if it exists in the map and update or create accordingly. Finally return map.values() which should return you a List.

Comment: Actually I was intending to return a list of all people and their tags. The code i provided isn't accurate,I threw it together quickly. Your solution would work but i was hoping to use the group_concat function as if i have lots of tags and lots or people i think it would be quicker. +1 though for spotting the easy solution i had completely overlooked this.